# how to display &nbsp; in Mozilla using XSL.

Tags: firefox, xslt

How can I display `&nbsp;` in Mozilla using XSL. I've tried CDATA but that didn't work.

I am using Firefox 3.5.5

Answer (score 6):

As you can't place an HTML character entity directly into your XSLT source (except for `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;`, `&quot;` and `&amp;`) you will need to go with numerical entities. So you should to use:

```
&#160;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the character entity `&#160;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;`.